# npm run build does not update assets

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have a ReactJS project with the following layout:

```
assets
dist
notes_module
src
tools
package.json
package-lock.json
webpack.config.dev.js
webpack.config.prod.js
...
```

Inside the assets folder, I have a PNG file (*user.png*) that is rendered in the index.html. Now, I have deleted the png physically from the directory, run `npm run build` command and expected error message instead of the png file when loading the page from the browser, but the strange think is that the file is still loaded which means that `assets` in the `dist` is not updated.

Also, when I run `npm start`, I see

```
     Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
3e1af3ef546b9e6ecef9f3ba197bf7d2.ttf     172 kB          [emitted]
                          sprite.png    41.5 kB          [emitted]
ec4c9962ba54eb91787aa93d361c10a8.ttf     171 kB          [emitted]
ee7b96fa85d8fdb8c126409326ac2d2b.ttf     171 kB          [emitted]
fc84e998bc29b297ea20321e4c90b6ed.ttf     170 kB          [emitted]
d08840599e05db7345652d3d417574a9.ttf     172 kB          [emitted]
                            user.png     126 kB          [emitted]
                        sprite2x.png    97.5 kB          [emitted]
                        sprite3x.png     159 kB          [emitted]
                        sprite4x.png     222 kB          [emitted]
                           bundle.js    22.2 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
                          index.html  770 bytes          [emitted]
```

Among this list, you can see the *user.png* file which does exist physically any more. I am completely stuck at this moment. Any help?

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: You mean the browser? I've done hard load.

Comment: Yep the browser. Try clearing the cache from the inspector. You could open it in incognito either.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to open the page in Incognito. But as you see, the problem is not even in the browser, because when I run "npm start", I can see that the file is being processed as you can see from the list that I've provided in the question

Comment: Have you tried clearing the npm cache?

Comment: Please try to remove dist folder and then make build again.

Comment: Did this as well. It created the dist folder, and the user.pgn file inside it )